# NativeScript valueChanges never emits when binding formControl on a TextField

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, angular-forms, nativescript-angular

I have a `TextField` and I'm trying to use a `formControl` binding on it like this:

```
<TextField class="input right" [formControl]="query"></TextField>
```

So I can then listen for changes like this:

```
  public query = new FormControl('');

  ...

  this.querySubscription = this.query.valueChanges.subscribe((query) => {
      console.log(query);
      this.places.search(this.query.value)
        .then((places) => {
          this.searchResults = places;
          console.log(this.searchResults);
        }, (error => {
          // TODO: Handle error
          console.log(error);
      }));
    });
```

The module it resides in:

```
import { SharedModule } from '../../shared/shared.module';
import { MapRoutingModule } from './map-routing.module.tns';
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { MapComponent } from './map.component';
import { NativeScriptCommonModule } from 'nativescript-angular/common';
import { NativeScriptUISideDrawerModule } from 'nativescript-ui-sidedrawer/angular';
import { NativeScriptFormsModule } from 'nativescript-angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    NativeScriptCommonModule,
    // NativeScriptFormsModule,
    MapRoutingModule,
    NativeScriptUISideDrawerModule,
    SharedModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    MapComponent,
  ],
  schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
})

export class MapModule {}
```

The problem is that `valueChanges` never triggers.. then I thought "oh I might be missing `NativeScriptFormsModule` so I tried adding that to `MapModule`'s `imports` but then I get an error instead saying `No provider for ngControl`, so I removed it again.

What could I be doing wrong here?

Comment: try to include `NativeScriptFormsModule` and `ReactiveFormsModule`

Comment: @JohnVelasquez Ofc.. Didn't try both of them at once for some reason. If you post it as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

include `NativeScriptFormsModule` and `ReactiveFormsModule`should be fine :)